# How can I display very large fractions nicely?

Tags: equations, formatting, fractions, nicefrac

I want to replicate the following fraction:
[image: large fraction with sums]

However, I don't know, how I can get this nice diagonal fraction line. The `nicefrac` package did not display it like I would like to.

So far I used

```
\frac{dN}{dS} = \nicefrac{\frac{\sum_{p \in G}i_p^N}{T_G^N}}{\frac{\sum_{p \in G}i_p^S}{T_G^S}}
```

but that looks like this:
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

`\middle` but adjust the space slightly

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\frac{dN}{dS} = \left.\frac{\sum_{p \in G}i_p^N}{T_G^N}
                \!\middle/\,
               \frac{\sum_{p \in G}i_p^S}{T_G^S}\right.
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't even know I can use `\left.` to produce an invisible character. What exactly does `\! ... \` do?

Comment: @skranz `\!`is negative thin space (same width as `\,`but in the other direction) so here the total width of `/` is the same but I pulled it slightly under the numerator on the left and spaced it a little from the right.  Try it without the `\!`and `\,`and see

Answer (score 3):

You can use `\left/` and `\right.` to get what you want, and so the `nicefrac` package isn't necessary.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[\frac{dN}{dS} = \frac{\sum_{p \in G}i_p^N}{T_G^N}\left/~\frac{\sum_{p \in G}i_p^S}{T_G^S}\right.\]

\end{document}
```

[image]