# How to add big slash to equation?

Tags: math-mode, equations

```
\begin{equation}
A = \frac{\frac{BBBBBBBB}{CCCCCCCC}}{\frac{DDDDDDDDD}{EEEEEEEEE}}
\end{equation}
```

I want to add the equation as shown in the figure (I have written in MS Word) but I want to write same in `LaTeX`. Can anyone help me with this?

[image: Word][image: Output from LATEX]

Comment: Please try with `\bigg/` Also note that please post your `MWE` as executable format always, i.e., from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/639580/how-can-i-display-very-large-fractions-nicely does half the job: it prints the large slash but doesn't offset the denominator/numerator vertically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just write `\frac{AAA}{BBB} \bigg/ \frac{CCC}{DDD}`.

If, in addition, you want to raise the first fraction and lower the second fraction, you could encase the fraction terms in `\raisebox` wrappers with suitably chosen amounts of displacement. While you're at it, you may want to bring the displaced fractions closer to the tall slash symbol, say by adding `\!` (negative thinspace) instructions. Speaking for myself, I don't think a useful purpose is served by applying such vertical displacement operations.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'align*' env.
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
A &= \frac{BBBBBBBB}{CCCCCCCC} \bigg/ \frac{DDDDDDDDD}{EEEEEEEEE} \\[2ex]
  &= \raisebox{1.5ex}{$\dfrac{BBBBBBBB}{CCCCCCCC}$}
     \!\! \Bigg/ \!\!
     \raisebox{-1.5ex}{$\dfrac{DDDDDDDDD}{EEEEEEEEE}$} = \cdots
\end{align*} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Mico, it worked.